# Finding strings shared between two dataframe columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, intersection

I have a data frame with two columns of delimited strings:

```
df <- data.frame('a'=c('a, b, c, d', 'a, c', 'b, d'), 'b'=c('a, d', 'a', 'a, d'))

           a      b
1 a, b, c, d   a, d
2       a, c      a
3       b, d   a, d
```

And I would like to create a third column to include the strings that intersect the first two columns, for example:

```
           a      b      c
1 a, b, c, d   a, d   a, d
2       a, c      a      a
3       b, d   a, d      d
```

I have tried a number of approaches that involve converting the strings to lists and back but I don't seem to be able to get it right.

Using `dplyr` I first attempted to use:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(c=paste(c(intersect(unlist(strsplit(a, split=", ")), unlist(strsplit(b, split=", "))))))
```

Which resulted in an error:

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
>         wrong result size (2), expected 3 or 1

As well as not returning the required string, this also seems to return results of the same size for each row (verified by changing the `mutate` function above from `paste` to `length` below):

```
df %>%
    mutate(c=length(c(intersect(unlist(strsplit(a, split=", ")), unlist(strsplit(b, split=", "))))))

           a    b   c
1 a, b, c, d a, d   2
2       a, c    a   2
3       b, d a, d   2
```

Which makes me worry that all my row results are being combined into one result and repeated.

To try to simplify things I attempted to convert my strings into lists before using the intersect function:

```
df %>% mutate(a_list=list(unlist(strsplit(a, split=", "))))
```

But received the error:

> Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
>          not compatible with STRSXP

Which makes wonder if lists in data frames are compatible with the `tidyverse` and, as such, if I need to take an entirely different approach.

Any advice on how to approach the problem of finding strings shared between two data frame columns in R  (as well as any insight into how to treat list like values in data frames) would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This base R method will work: use `strsplit` to split the variables into lists with each element a vector of characters. The `mapply` function takes the lists and applies the following operation to pairs of elements in each list that are in the same postion. Then use `insersect` to find overlapping elements and `paste` with collapse to paste these together.

```
df$c <- mapply(function(x, y) paste(intersect(x, y), collapse=", "),
               strsplit(df$a, ", "), strsplit(df$b, ", "))

df
           a    b    c
1 a, b, c, d a, d a, d
2       a, c    a    a
3       b, d a, d    d
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame('a'=c('a, b, c, d', 'a, c', 'b, d'),
                 'b'=c('a, d', 'a', 'a, d'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: That's great, thanks, I was perhaps a little over keen to use dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
library(stringr)
# go go through each row, extract the letters, search for duplicates and paste together
apply(df, 1, function(x){
  tmp <- str_trim(unlist(str_split(x,",")))
  paste(tmp[duplicated(tmp)],collapse=", ")
 })
[1] "a, d" "a"   "d"
```